# Add customer email in a new column to admin orders list on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, orders

I  am trying to find a way on how to add the customer email in the header row on the WooCommerce order view.

Any ideas, tips or pointers on how to make this happen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add the user email as a separated column, you will use the following:

```
// Add custom column after "Order number" column in admin orders list
add_filter('manage_edit-shop_order_columns', 'add_user_email_order_column', 10, 1 );
function add_user_email_order_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ($columns as $key => $column ){
        $new_columns[$key] = $column;
        // Insert the new column after 'order_number'
        if( $key === 'order_number'){
            $new_columns['customer_email'] = __("Email", "woocommerce");
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}

// Display data to custom column in admin orders list
add_action( 'manage_shop_order_posts_custom_column' , 'display_user_email_order_column', 10, 2 );
function display_user_email_order_column( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $the_order;

    if( $column  === 'customer_email' ) {

        if( $the_order->get_customer_id() ){
            $email = $the_order->get_billing_email(); // Billing email

            // Outpup the email
            echo '<a href="mailto:'.$email.'" class="user-view"><strong>'.$email.'</strong></a>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: The column email shows but it is empty. Any idea on how to make it work on the latest WooCommerce?

Comment: @VanDerPrygel Sorry but the code works perfectly on last WooCommerce version 4.7.0 (Just tested now).

Comment: That's strange, maybe there is made some custom code on the Webshop I am working on. I will post it here if I find the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @VanDerPrygel The code still works perfectly on last WooCommerce version.